# Cutting a Solid with a sharp edged tool

Tags: solid-state-chemistry

[image]

The third point of difference suggests that amorphous solids can't be cut into two parts of regular surfaces 
But glass being an amorphous solid is cut into regular pieces often.
What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your textbook is correct. Glass surface may appear smooth, but in reality it is really rough and irregular if viewed under a microscope. [Here](http://www.fch.akbild.ac.at/Forschung-ProjekteCorrosionMM.html) you will find some pictures. Have you ever seen an insect walking on a window? It is possible because of those irregularities on the glass surface. Insect legs have tiny hooks which graple to all these lumps, cracks and holes on the glass.

Comment: everything is rough when viewed under a microscope. I don't think anyone can possibly attain a smooth surface. The problem is that how can I judge if a solid is uniform  throughout(crstalline) or not (amorphous) on the basis of whether it can be cut smoothly thorugh just one of its layers